# Displaying PDF file in WebView is not working - Titanium

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

We are using Ti SDK 8.0.0 GA and running app in iOS 12.2 device. 
try to load PDF from document folder. It is unable to load. It is Working fine in Simulators.

And also working fine in Ti SDK 7.5.1 GA.

```
Ti.UI.createWebView({
url : factSheetPath,
scalesPageToFit : true,
backgroundColor : "transparent",
disableBounce : true,
willHandleTouches : true
});
```

`factSheetPath` is something like this

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8F59DFDF-E475-4383-96DC-2DCC5FDDC2DB/Documents/download/pdf_factsheets/1.pdf
```

any suggestions!

Comment: Moving to tmp folder and opening it in WebView works. But it looks like something wrong in SDK or iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this Appc JIRA ticket
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25680

We moved PDF to tmp folder and try to open that tmp folder PDF file in webview it worked well.

Sample code also there in above JIRA link. Copied same code here.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor: '#fff'
});

var btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
  title: 'Open PDF'
});

btn.addEventListener('click', openPDF);

win.add(btn);
win.open();

// Open the PDF file
function openPDF() {
  var fileName = 'example.pdf';

  // For iOS 11.2, workaround the Apple issue by creating a temporary file and
  // reference it. It will be removed from filesystem once the app closes.
  // Read more here: http://nshipster.com/nstemporarydirectory/
  if (isiOS11_2()) {
    fileName = fileInTemporaryDirectory(fileName);
  }

  var docViewer = Ti.UI.iOS.createDocumentViewer({
    url: fileName
  });

  docViewer.show();
}

// Check if the current device runs iOS 11.2+
function isiOS11_2() {
    var version = Ti.Platform.version.split(".");   
    return (parseInt(version[0]) >= 11 && parseInt(version[1]) >= 2);
}

// Create a temporary file with the contents of the old file
// Expects the file to be in the resources directory. If you receive the file 
// from an API-call, receive pass the Ti.Blob/Ti.File/text to "write" directly.
function fileInTemporaryDirectory(fileName) {
  var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, fileName);

  if (!file.exists()) {
    alert('File does not exist in resources!');
    return;
  }

  var newFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.tempDirectory, fileName);
  newFile.createFile();

  if (!newFile.exists()) {
    alert('New file could not be created in temporary directory!');
    return;
  }

  newFile.write(file);

  return newFile.nativePath;
}
```

Comment: My file doesn't open with Document viewer tried temp and data directory both.